# LLVM, unions, pointer casts and undefined behavior

Tags: c, clang, llvm, undefined-behavior

Clang seems to translate unions into the most strictly aligned member type and then make free use of pointer casts, e.g.

```
union U {
  double x;
  int y;
};

int f(union U *u) { return u->y; }
```

Compiles to

```
%union.U = type { double }

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define i32 @f(%union.U* %u) #0 {
  %1 = alloca %union.U*, align 8
  store %union.U* %u, %union.U** %1, align 8
  %2 = load %union.U*, %union.U** %1, align 8
  %3 = bitcast %union.U* %2 to i32*
  %4 = load i32, i32* %3, align 8
  ret i32 %4
}
```

I'm surprised, because casting a pointer to a different type and then dereferencing it, is generally undefined behavior. Of course, LLVM IR isn't obliged to follow the same UB rules as C, but for the most part it does - that's how Clang follows the C UB rules, it just transcribes the code fairly directly into IR and lets the backend deal with it.

So how/why, exactly, is this a valid way to deal with unions?

To add some clarification: the above IR is basically the same as is generated by the following C:

```
struct U {
  double x;
};

int f(struct U *u) { return *(int*)u; }
```

with the only difference being that the final `align 8` becomes `align 4`. I would expect the second C code fragment to be UB, but the first isn't, therefore the second must not be. So why is the second C code fragment not UB?

Comment: This is below the language level, so the UB rules do not apply. At the machine code level, a union and its members all share the same address.

Comment: @BoPersson It's below the C level yes, but it's above the machine code level. Unlike machine code, LLVM IR applies most of the C rules about undefined behavior. If you say there are some it doesn't apply, I'm prepared to believe you, but is there a document that says exactly what the exceptions are?

Comment: From what I remember, C11 allows you to access any member of a union and it will try to interpret the bits as a value of the type you access. This will be a problem if there are trap representations for some types. Perhaps LLVM doesn't target systems where an `int` will trap.

Comment: @BoPersson True, but the generated IR has no knowledge of unions. I have added some hopeful clarification - the real point is that the generated IR is the same as that generated from an alternative C code fragment that knows nothing of unions and looks like UB, so why isn't it?

Comment: Clang is letting you shoot yourself in the foot.  Undefined Behavior does not mean the compiler is guaranteed to reject the code, or even warn you about it!

Comment: @Davislor: If a compiler fails--as clang 3.9 does--to abide by any remotely-plausible reading of the Standard--I wouldn't describe that behavior as "letting someone shoot themselves in the foot".  Look at https://godbolt.org/g/3OEwm6 for example.  The generated machine code will store a 6 to the first pointer, a 3 to the second, and then unconditionally return 6.  If the Common Initial Sequence rule wouldn't forbid that optimization, what does it do?

Comment: @supercat The common-subexpression rule allows code to **inspect** the fields of an inactive member, not to set them.  That’s probably why the Clang writers would say it’s not a bug.  With some testing, if we copy over the entire structure inside the field with `memcpy()`, the code inspects the common subexpression correctly on Clang 3.8.0.

Comment: @supercat On further testing, though, using `memset()` to initialize the inactive structure before setting one of its does not work: clang still assumes the pointers are not aliases even without the `restrict` keyword.  This looks like a bug to me.  The `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag suppresses this spurious optimization and makes Clang compile the code correctly.

Comment: @Davislor: The act of writing to a union member is *what makes it active*.  After the first write, `v1` will be the active member of `*u1`.  After the second write, `v2` will be the active member of `*u2`.  If `u1` and `u2` alias, the second write will change the active member of `*u1` to `v2`, which is allowable.  Only the read could involve an inactive union member, and since the purpose of that read is to inspect a member of the CIS, it too is allowable.

Comment: @Davislor: The Standard doesn't make clear whether writing to a union member through a pointer *to that member* makes it the active member, but that isn't happening here.  If the Standard had guaranteed the ability to "access", rather than "inspect", that would suggest that given something like `struct foo {long l; short s;} *pfoo; struct bar {long l; short s,t;}; union u {struct foo vfoo; struct bar vbar;};` a write to `pfoo->s` would be forbidden from disturbing any padding that follows that field, even on platforms where preserving that padding would be expensive.

Comment: @Davislor: The real problem is that most uses of the aliasing rule require a definition of "object" which is different from the definition used elsewhere in the Standard.  If I were in charge of writing a standard which balanced what compilers do and what programmers require, I would coin a new term *object view*, and say that an access to an object via a pointer creates an "object view" and allow compilers to assume that an object for which an active view exists will only be accessed in certain ways.  That would allow some optimizations not allowable under present rules, but...

Comment: ...also avoid the need for programmers to perform redundant data-copying operations to get around aliasing rules.  For `memcpy` to work, the storage returned by `malloc(N)` needs to be seen as "an object", regardless of what is stored in it; that works if `memcpy(N)` returns a pointer to an untyped object that is N bytes long, and would cause no difficulty with aliasing rules if they are recognized as only being applicable to objects with types.

Comment: @supercat This discussion is veering off-topic, and you also seem to be thinking of the C++ standard and linking to an example of a C++ compiler.  That’s an interesting subject as well, but this is a C question.

Comment: @Davislor: I'm focused on the C Standard.  C99 added a concept of an object's "effective type", but failed to formulate a definition of "object" which is consistent both with that usage and with other uses of the term.

Comment: I seem to recall that your interpretation of the standard means literally every C program that uses dynamic memory must trigger UB.

Comment: @Davislor: I believe that the authors of C89 intended that compilers would continue to treat as defined a number of constructs which common sense would imply should be defined on at least some platforms, without the Standard having to list all of them.  The Standard fails to provide some guarantees which are necessary to implement practical and efficient dynamic-memory-management code on freestanding implementations which don't provide `malloc()` not because the writers thought compilers shouldn't provide such guarantees, but because they couldn't imagine compiler writers failing to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example is undefined behavior.  On some real-world architectures, `double` has stricter alignment requirements than `int`.  It’s even possible to imagine some esoteric architecture where integers and floating-point variables are stored in different regions of memory to run more efficiently on a separate ALU and FPU.  Doing it the other way around, casting the address of an `int` to a `double*` and dereferencing it, when the `int` is not part of the same `union` as `double`, might crash the program with a `SIGBUS` error on 32-bit Sparc Solaris, for example.

Even doing the conversion on an improperly-aligned pointer is UB (as just loading an invalid pointer into a register might crash the program on some systems, such as invalid segment selectors in legacy x86 protected mode).  See sections J.2 and §6.3.2.3.  Be aware that the one change you noticed, relaxing the alignment restriction from 8-byte to 4-byte, allows the lower-order bits of the pointer to be `100` instead of `000`, and casting a pointer that ends in `100` to a pointer type that must end in `000` is already undefined behavior.  (To be pedantic, the one exception is that casting a null pointer to any other pointer type is always safe and gives you a null pointer of the new type.)

Undefined behavior means the compiler is allowed to do anything, and that includes doing what you literally said and doing what you meant.  Since you explicitly cast the pointer in your second example, Clang is letting you potentially shoot yourself in the foot.

What about your first example, with two union members?  You’re guaranteed to get the address of a valid `int` object.  According to the [C11 Draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (§6.2.5.28), “All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.  Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.”  Footnote 41 on page 40 says specifically, “The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions.”  In §6.7.2.1.16, “A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members [...], and vice versa.”

It’s certainly valid to implement suitable conversion as the identity function!  The compiler can represent pointers in whatever way makes sense on that architecture, and the standard guarantees that the representation of the pointer is valid for both objects.

That said, if it reads an inactive member of the union, the value is unspecified.  If you set `u.y` and read `u.x`, on a target where `int` is less than 64 bits wide, the remaining bits of the object representation of `u.x` might be anything, including a trap representation.  Or, if you set `u.x` and read `u.y`, the value will depend on the details of how `int` and `double` are represented.

Comment: On clang, reading an inactive member of the union isn't guaranteed to work even if the data read was part of a Common Initial Sequence which is shared between the active member and the member read.

Comment: §6.5.2.3.6: “One special guarantee is made in order to simplify the use of unions: if a union contains several  structures that share a common initial sequence (see below), and if the union object currently contains one of these structures, it is permitted to inspect the common initial part of any of them anywhere that a declaration of the completed type of the union is visible.” The best-known example is the `sa_family` field of `struct sockaddr`, so most programs that transmit or receive data depend on this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is defined. If a member, that wasn't written last, is read, then the bytes represented by this member are reinterpreted in the new type. The type may be a trap representation, which in case you will get undefined behavior, but unlikely on a modern machine.

The second example is undefined behavior because of aliasing rules. The union is accessed by the type int, which is not compatible with types struct U or double.

Correct code is one of possible outcomes of undefined behavior.